# Query Database, save results as an object and then fill a DataGridView with the properties of the object

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

Testing the waters on C#. I have a Winform program where the user registers employees through a form. The user's data is stored in a table from an SQL Server database.
In another section of the program, the user should be able to display all of the registered employees and their information. However, I cannot use a DataSet or a DataTable. So I was thinking about doing something like this (conceptually)

***Query the database > Create a new instance of the appropriate class > store said object in a list > fill up the DataGridView by looping through the list.***

However, I don't know how to "translate" the query results into individual instances of the class. The query won't always return just 1 row, but several of them, so how can you do it so that each row goes through the process of being added as the values of the properties of every new instance that I'm storing in the list?

Assuming the example class is something like "Employee" with Properties "ID", "Name" and "Position"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just set the properties to the DB values.

```
List<Employee> myEmployees = new List<Employee>();
foreach(DataRow dr in myDatatable.Rows)
{
  new myEmployee = new Employee {ID = dr["ID"], Name = dr["Name"], Postion = dr["Postion"]};
  myEmployees.Add(myEmployee);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of myDataTabla? I thought it meant a DataTable object, but I get a "foreach loop cannot operate on variables of type DataTable"

Comment: @Elmambo2194 - sorry should be myDataTable.Rows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database returns the ID, Name and Position as variables you can use an ObservableCollection to populate e.g. a DataGrid.
Initially create a class storing the Employee data.

```
public class Employee
{
  public int ID{get; set;}
  public string name{get; set;}
  public string position{get; set;}
}
```

Next in yout MainWindow define a dependency property (Employees).

```
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
{
  get{return (ObservableCollection<Employee>) GetValue(EmpProperty);}
  set{SetValue(EmpProperty, value);}
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty EmpProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
(
  "Employees", typeof(ObservableCollection<Employee>),
  typeof(MainWindow),
  new PropertyMetadata(null)
);
```

At another place in your MainWindow you get the query result; for simplicity I assume three arrays ID_Array, name_Array and position_Array storing count elements in my example

```
...
Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>
{
  for(int i = 0, i < count; i++)
  {
    new Employee
    {
      ID = ID_Array[i],
      name = name_Array[i],
      position = position_Array[i];
    };
  }
}
...
PART_DataGrid.ItemsSource = Employees;
```

Finally in your xaml file declare your DataGrid

```
...
<DataGrid x:Name="PART_DataGrid", AutogenerateColumns="false">
  DataGrid.Columns>
  <!-- Define headers as needed -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding position}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I haven't tested the code yet but I hope it gives you a basic idea on how to proceed. Basically it shoud work with WinForms as well.

Regards Martin

Comment: This is WinForms, not WPF. What you posted cannot work (except the `Employee` class definition).